# Problem with implementation XAPP495

Tags: fpga, signal, spartan, hdmi, spartan-6

I'm working on [XAPP495](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp495_S6TMDS_Video_Interface.pdf) to show a signal which is throughput of a HDMI signal from my Laptop

I do this steps:

1. created a new ISE project
2. added all of the .v files from XAPP495
3. added dvi_demo.ucf
4. set dvi_demo as the top module
5. generated a programming file
6. programmed it in to my [Digilent Atlys board](http://store.digilentinc.com/atlys-spartan-6-fpga-trainer-board-limited-time-see-nexys-video/)
7. connected HDMI cable from my laptop to the HDMI in on the board
8. connected HDMI cable from the HDMI out on the broad to HDMI in on a screen

But the screen show that there is no signal.
I searched about this problem and see that there is a solution to buy a DVI splitter, but I can't add another components to me design.

And there is another solution is to use windows apps can downloaded to display the EDID of DVI/HDMI monitors.
I search about it and follow some steps but it seems soooo complex to done.

Is there is any other way to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you set the DIP switches correctly? Did you pay attention to any error messages created while generating the programming file? There is not nearly enough detail here to allow anyone to help you debug your problem.

Comment: You need to write an EDID module. The XAPP495 does not include any form of EDID code. You will need an I2C slave HDL module connected externally to the HDMI's DDC connections, and internally connected to a small amount of ROM. You will then need to have that ROM programmed with EDID data for your screen. Otherwise the laptop won't know what to display.

Comment: @DaveTweed yes I did and there was an error while generating the programming file but I correct it ,, so the problem is on the Tx which is my laptop.

Comment: @TomCarpenter is there any manual or website or anything that I can follow to do this ,,, I start doing the steps on this website but I lost :( http://www.komeil.com/blog/fix-edid-monitor-no-signal-dvi

Comment: @TomCarpenter: Or you could just wire the EDID connections from the monitor straight through to the laptop. Of course, doing this inside the FPGA gets tricky, given that SDA is bidirectional ... problem left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: You won't find a guide on how to do it. You're not fixing something on your laptop or whatever. You need to physically create the hardware for the EDID in your FPGA. You need to first write or find an I2C slave core, and instantiate it along with some ROM. You can use an EDID editor software to create the data that needs to be in your ROM.

Comment: @DaveTweed Ah I see, didn't read that there were two monitors involved. Yes, the simplest way is to pass the data through.

Comment: in fact the board already has the hardware to do it.

Comment: @TomCarpenter thanks very much I will start searching and understanding for the things you said :)

Comment: @TomCarpenter may you please see the comment on Your Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAPP495 does not have any form of EDID handling. However, as you are using the Digilent Atlys board, and are having one HDMI input and one HDMI output, then as long as you use the correct HDMI ports, EDID handling becomes much simpler.

Essentially you just need to pass the EDID signals from the output port (the one connected to your monitor) through to the input port (the one connected to your laptop). The Atlys board already has provision to do this via some external jumpers.

According to page 13 of the [Reference Manual](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/university/XUP%20Boards/XUPAtlys/documentation/Atlys_rm.pdf):

[image: Diagram]

If you use port J2 for your output, and port J3 for your input, then connecting the EDID pins is simply a case of installing jumpers on JP6 and JP7 to connect the SCL and SDA signals of the two EDID I2C buses.

Comment: Thanks very much for you help ,, I done the same thing you said and to make sure I'm doing the right thig I follow this website https://joelw.id.au/FPGA/DigilentAtlysResources 
Install jumpers on the anonymous header labelled SDA/SCL next to J1 (they're called JP2 on the schematic, though). On the boards I've seen and heard about, these were supplied from the factory with jumpers connected, but installed incorrectly, shorting SDA and SCL together on both sides rather than passing them through. Check the schematic diagram to see if this applies to you and then rotate them if necessary

Comment: I do this too ,,,  I tried all combinations of settings for sw0 and sw1 but still have noooo signal :( :(

Comment: hey again sorry for sending too much to you but I really need your help ,,, I follow alll the steps on this website  https://joelw.id.au/FPGA/DigilentAtlysResources and have the same problem " no signal " could you pleaseeee help me :(